# Insert values in table (mssql server) via PhP by using pdo

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I could not insert values in table (MSSQL) by using pdo php. I got message that connection is established but query does not work. I have never used MSSQL server I am not sure is this query good.

```
$database = "db";
$server = "xxx\SQLEXPRESS";
$conn = array( "Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"xxx" , "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
if( $conn ) {
     echo "connection established";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }

 // insert values into table, 
 // variables are defined above didnt write them here

$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dbo.FKNarudzbaKupacaStavke(IdFirma, VrstaDokumenta, BrojDokumenta, BrojDokumentaKroz, 
                        DatumDokumenta, IdKupac, VrstaCijene, NacinPlacanja, DatumZadnjeAkcije, Status, StatusArhive, StatusIzmjene, 
                        StatusStampe, VrstaFakture) VALUES(:IdFirma, :VrstaDokumenta, :BrojDokumenta, :BrojDokumentaKroz, :DatumDokumenta, :IdKupac, :VrstaCijene, :NacinPlacanja, 
                        :DatumZadnjeAkcije, :Status, :StatusArhive, :StatusIzmjene, :StatusStampe, :VrstaFakture)");

    $query->bindParam(':IdFirma',$IdFirma);
    $query->bindParam(':VrstaDokumenta',$VrstaDokumenta);
    $query->bindParam(':BrojDokumenta',$BrojDokumenta);
    $query->bindParam(':BrojDokumentaKroz',$BrojDokumentaKroz);
    $query->bindParam(':DatumDokumenta',$DatumDokumenta);
    $query->bindParam(':IdKupac',$IdKupac);
    $query->bindParam(':VrstaCijene',$VrstaCijene);
    $query->bindParam(':NacinPlacanja',$NacinPlacanja);
    $query->bindParam(':DatumZadnjeAkcije',$DatumZadnjeAkcije);
    $query->bindParam(':Status',$Status);
    $query->bindParam(':StatusArhive',$StatusArhive);
    $query->bindParam(':StatusIzmjene',$StatusIzmjene);
    $query->bindParam(':StatusStampe',$StatusStampe);
    $query->bindParam(':VrstaFakture',$VrstaFakture);
    $query->execute();
```

I got this error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object..

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written it, `$conn` isn't a connection, it's just an array.

Try this to connect to the database:

```
$hostname = 'xxx\SQLEXPRESS';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'xxx';
$dbname   = 'db';    
$conntype = 'mysql'; //or dblib or mssql

try {
    $conn = new PDO("$conntype:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
}

catch( PDOException $e ) {
    echo( $e->getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: actually he is trying to connect to mssql there for the mysql pdo driver wont work.

Comment: See my edit - added support for `mysql`, `dblib` or `mssql`

Comment: It does not work even if I changed it I got this error "Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\xampp-develop\htdocs\websoft\pages\brzaprodaja\insert_nalog.php on line 137
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in D:\xampp-develop\htdocs\websoft\pages\brzaprodaja\insert_nalog.php on line 145
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in D:\xampp-develop\htdocs\websoft\pages\brzaprodaja\insert_nalog.php on line 145"

Comment: If it says "no such host is known" then `$hostname` is incorrect. If you're on localhost, change it to `127.0.0.1`. If not, point it directly to the IP of your database host.

Comment: I got message could not find driver. I am using php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll so I am not sure if that is right driver. It is enabled in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not establishing the connection there, please change your $conn variable as show below

```
$conn = new PDO("mssql:host=".$server.";dbname=db", "user", "xxx");
```